# Preserve a promise in R

Tags: r

I want to, essentially, pass a value untouched through a function. So in the following example (in Rstudio):

```
example_function <- function(datain){
   as.environment("package:utils")$View(datain)
}
```

I want the inner function to act as if I'm passing it the original object, in particular so the name which appears in the View window will have the name of the original object (X, say) rather than datain which is what currently occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `deparse(substitute(datain))` you can get the original name of the argument passed.

Then, to accomplish what you asked for, you can simply do

```
example_function <- function(datain){
  as.environment("package:utils")$View(datain, deparse(substitute(datain)))
}
```

Now the View window will be titled appropriately as you wanted.

However note that "I want the inner function to act as if I'm passing it the original object" request of yours is not possible in R. R does not support pass-by-reference. There are some workarounds, but if you only needed if for naming the View, the above fix should be fine.

Comment: Ha, I spent so long trying to trick R to do something it couldn't it didn't occur to me to actually read the help file of View! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `get` for this.

```
example_function <- function(datain){
  as.environment("package:utils")$View(get(datain),datain)
}
```

in this case you don't pass the variable but rather the name of the variable as a string.

```
example_function("X")
```